# How to detect methods that can have a more restrictive access specifier

Tags: c++, c++11, static-analysis

I would like to analyze a bunch C++ source code files to detect if any of the methods of the defined classes may have a more restrictive access specifier.  The simple case would be methods that at the beginning were declared as `public` but later on only the owner class invokes them, so they could be moved to `private`.

Is there any automatic tool for that?  I'm working in Linux, the code is `C++11`-compliant, and I'm playing with several `clang` tools, in order to build my own, but if anyone can point me to an already existing tool it will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Whether or not the classes' own member functions access the member in question is immaterial. Checking that **nothing else** does this however, has to be done in the entire project, not just the compilation unit. It might also be pointed out that just because nobody calls a public member function, doesn't mean it has to be private. Especially in case of (virtual) inheritance.

Comment: I do not understand. The compiler will already tell you all this, or at least any cases of it that violate the semantics of C++, such as overriden methods that have become more private. Please provide a concrete instance of what you're trying to detect that the compiler won't already detect.

Comment: Sorry, I never talked about just the compilation unit; I said "only the owner class invokes them", meaning that no other element in the entire project does it.  I take your point though and you are right in the case of virtual inheritance.  I just look for a tool that tells me which public methods can be made private without any doubt, and perhaps point me to check those that might be (and it's for me to decide).

Comment: The compiler will tell me that a private method should be public, but not that a public method can be made private (as far as I know).

Comment: Have you tried cppcheck?

Comment: @Gupta No, I used in the past for general checking, but now I do not remember if it does what I want...  I will try.  Thanks!

Comment: @Gupta Apparently, cppcheck can tell you many useful things, as I remembered (like if you should pass by reference some arguments, or the need for copy constructors, etc.), but will not tell you that one of your public methods is used by its parent class and not used by any other class (and hence potentially could be moved to be private).

Comment: I was working with cppcheck a few years ago. I cannot remember such a feature on those versions as well. Would be nice if you could check ReSharper as well. In recent versions, they are supporting C++ as well.

Comment: @Gupta OK, i will try.  Anyway, as I said, I'm working on a simple python script that gets information from clang-check, parses it and then tries to find out if the public methods are used elsewhere; if not, they are signalled as potential private methods.  I will probably publish it somewhere, if anybody is interested...

Comment: Thanks. If published, just put the link here.